# Queued Laravel Mail not received by Gmail / Hotmail

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am recently experiencing a weird issue with sending Mails with Laravel 5.6.

Basically all the mails get received fine when it is executed in controllers with Sync. But for tinker / queued mail mailtrap / other email providers are able to receive the email. But Gmail / Hotmail does not receive it at all, not even in the Spam / Junk folder.

I have checked my PHP configuration and there is no major difference between the Apache version and the CLI version.

Also checked that my queue:work is running with supervisor and both the jobs / failed_jobs table are empty.

Not sure why is this happening, I am using SMTP as my mail driver and they are the exact same set for sending with queue and for sending in sync.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This is going to be extremely broad and tough to track down. First, in Laravel, start logging your email sends, and any responses you might get. Are you using sendmail to send email, or a 3rd party service? If it's a 3rd party service, see if you can find any logs on their side to see accepted and response messages. If you're using sendmail on linux, check the mail/exim logs in /var/logs for details.

Comment: make sure your `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` in your .env file. Confirm that and then we'll move forward with logging.

Comment: @Digvijay yes, QUEUE_CONNECTION=database in .env file

Comment: Alright! Let's add **Logs** to the **jobs** and before/after the **dispatch** call. See what you find. @RyanLiew

Comment: @RyanLiew have you found any solution?